# Formula manipulation (place interaction terms in proper order)

Tags: r, formula

I am trying to build up a model validation tool in which I am following a forward selection approach, so if we suppose my model is

```
model <- y ~ a * b + c * d + e
```

I can use the `terms` function

```
attributes(terms(model))$term.labels
```

to find out all the predictors in my model, but the problem with this approach is that interactions terms always get put at the end of the result. I want `a:b` to be after `a` and `b`, and not at the end, and same goes for `c:d`. Is there a way to keep the order with the interaction terms?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use `keep.order` in `terms.formula()`

```
model <- y ~ a * b + c * d + e
labels(terms(model, keep.order = TRUE))
# [1] "a"   "b"   "a:b" "c"   "d"   "c:d" "e"
```

To look up the help file, you will want to use `?terms.formula`, as this method is not shown in `?terms`. But `terms()` *will* dispatch to the formula method.  Additionally, `labels()` is a shorthand way to get the term labels from `terms()`.